# Problems linking msvc intrinsics using clang on windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, clang, intrinsics

I'm swapping over a large codebase from using msvc to clang for a windows product.  This product uses a large number of the msvc compiler intrinsics such as _InterlockedOr etc.  If I build a little test program using clang on windows it builds, links and runs just fine, but if I build a library from our product that uses an intrinsics it comes up as a missing symbol.

I've tried compiling both the test code and our product using the --verbose option and can't spot anything different between the two. The only difference in the way they are called is that the large product is built using fastbuild which necessitates the use of -c to prevent the compiler calling the linker as well.   Clang obviously adds in some libraries that are missing when I call the linker manually myself, so can anybody let me know what they might be?  (I'm already linking in the crt library (libcmt, msvcrt) so it's not that.

I've started writing my own library of intrinsics in assembly which is fun, but shouldn't be necessary.  Any one?

As per request, compiling the following code with clang works when using it directly, i.e. `clang IntrinsicsTest.cpp`produces an exe.

```
IntrinsicsTest.cpp
#include "stdio.h"
#include "intrin.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned long long r = __rdtsc();
    printf("Intrinsic: %llu\n", r);
}
```

Yet fails to link when called via fastbuild:
`FBuild.exe -showcmds -clean IntrinsicsTest_debug_x86`

> clang.exe "\IntrinsicsTest.cpp" -D_WINDOWS -c -m32 -mfpmath=sse -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -fno-rtti -fexceptions -E ...\IntrinsicsTest.debug.Win32.lib
>
> lib.exe /NOLOGO /OUT:"...\IntrinsicsTest.debug.Win32.lib" "...\IntrinsicsTest.obj" ...\IntrinsicsTest.debug.Win32.exe
>
> link.exe /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /OUT:"...\IntrinsicsTest.debug.Win32.exe" "...\IntrinsicsTest.obj" -defaultlib:libcmt.lib -INCREMENTAL -MANIFEST /MACHINE:X86 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:NOICF /OPT:NOREF
>
> IntrinsicsTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___rdtsc referenced in function
>   _wmain ...\IntrinsicsTest.debug.Win32.exe
>
> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Intrinsics are typically compiler extensions, and non-standard, therefore they are compiler-dependent.

Comment: Are you using clang-cl? mingw-w64 clang? MS clang/C2?

Comment: "Clang --version" gives me:
`clang version 3.8.0 (branches/release_38)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin`

Comment: Can you fix the formatting in that compiler output?  I'm not sure if that's all one command or not.  And try with `clang++`, so it's actually an error to call an undeclared function.

Comment: It's 3 commands called separately by fastbuild.  Hopefully the edit makes this clearer.  

I'm pretty sure that I can't use clang++ without a huge amount of effort changing the build tools as we have a mixed codebase of c and c++ (and assembly). clang seems to cope nicely swapping between the two, whereas clang++ never seems to compile as c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.  There were several contributing factors all to do with how fastbuild, clang and msvc were interacting.

a/ With Clang on Windows there is no need to specify "system" includes.
In our project we had the include paths as:

```
-I"C:/Program Files/LLVM/lib/clang/3.8.0/include" 
-I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/" 
-I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/atlmfc/include" 
-I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/include/um" 
-I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/include/shared"
-I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/include/winrt"
```

The clang version of xmmintrin declares the intrinsics inline and thus if this header is used then the test program compiles fine. The Windows xmmintrin declares the intrinsics as extern functions, hence the program compiles, but doesn't link - where an msvc build gets these symbols from is irrelevant now.

However, even with the clang include path first, when `<intrin.h>` is included by anything, it pulls in the windows header.

b/ Fastbuild allows you to set up environment variables for the build env. Our scripts have INCLUDE and PATH defined with msvc paths. Removing these helped.

c/ As well as clang, I have several versions of msvc installed on my machine.  Clang was picking up on MSVC14 whereas fastbuild was trying to get clang to use MSVC 12. By changing fastbuild to use MSVC14 I was finally able to get past the problem with the intrinsics.

Comment: Ah, that goes some way to explaining why headers with just prototypes might exist for things that are supposed to be intrinsics.  The prototypes might help IDEs and stuff, but probably the MSVC compiler itself already has internal built-in definitions for them the way gcc/clang have `__builtin_XYZ` pre-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Intrinsics aren't supposed to be function calls, they're supposed to inline to one or a couple instructions.  Or in some cases, no instructions (e.g. a compiler memory barrier, like c++'s `std::atomic_signal_fence`).

MSVC and GNU C are separate flavours of C.  clang implements GNU C, and AFAIK doesn't support MSVC intrinsics.

When there's a GNU C `__builtin_something` equivalent to an MSVC intrinsic, use it via a wrapper function.

mingw-w64 apparently does support `_Interlocked???`, via `<winnt.h>`.  [This mailing list post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.w64.general/7415) is a patch that switched over the implementation from inline asm to GNU C `__sync_fetch_and_???` functions.  IDK if that's shipping with current mingw, or if there's a mingw version of clang.  But that's what you should be looking for.  I'm sure you're not the first person to want to compile an MSVC codebase using a different compiler.

Comment: Clang on windows ships it's own `<Intrin.h>` with lots of MSVC's intrinsics. Some are just implemented directly, some mapped to LLVM supported intrinsics (including the `_Interlocked???` family), and some just declared (not sure if definitions for these are in some library or not).

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but it kind of ignores the main point of my question.  Clang on windows compiles msvc intrinsics just fine as they are included in its intrin.h.  However, if I manually link they come up as missing symbols. @melak47 It is my assumption as well that the definition is in some library, but I can't find out the name of that library.

Comment: @Teknogrebo: Which intrinsics are you having a problem with?  Like I said in the first paragraph, most should inline at compile time, so the linker isn't part of the picture.  If there's a link-time problem, it means you weren't getting proper inline/builtin definitions for them.  Maybe edit your question with a minimal example of a function that builds fine in a stand-alone executable but not as a library?  That seems to be what you're getting at.

Comment: @PeterCordes I appreciate that they *should* be being inlined. But empirically in my case they aren't.  There is a massive long list of missing symbols when I build our product, of which __mm_add_ps, __mm_store_ss, __cpuid, _InterlockedOr, and _BitScanForward are just a small subset of.  As for minimal examples, the code is irrelevant as it is the process that is broken, but I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: @Teknogrebo: Then the problem isn't actually linking, it's it's in the compile step.  `_mm_add_ps` (one leading underscore) will always compile to an `addps` instruction, not a function call (even at `-O0`), as long as you've included the appropriate header (`<immintrin.h>` is the modern choice, but there's also a whole series of headers starting with `<xmmintrin.h>` for different generations of intrinsics.)  If your source code actually has double-underscore versions, that might be a problem.  Are you sure your code compiles without a ton of `implicit declaration` warnings?

Comment: @PeterCordes The actual code base I am trying to build uses _mm_add_ps and there are no __mm* functions to be found. I haven't disabled any warnings to do with implicit declarations and none are generated.  The minimal code example I added to the question certainly doesn't give any warnings and exhibits the behaviour I am trying to get to the bottom of.

Comment: @Teknogrebo: Ok, thanks for checking on that.  Probably `"intrin.h"` is just providing declarations, but not definitions, for most of those intrinsics.  That's not going to be useful for making fast code, because you *need* definitions to be visible at compile-time to avoid function-call overhead.  (except maybe if link-time-optimization works?).  For `_mm*` intrinsics, just include `<immintrin.h>`.  Other than that, I'm out of ideas, since I don't even have a Windows machine.